# how to save mysql ouput with queries into a cav file

Tags: mysql-8.0

I'm trying to save MySQL output with query into CSV file.

```
SELECT 'stud_id'

UNION ALL

/* Now the actual query */
SELECT students.stud_id 

FROM students 

/* Save the query results to a file */
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/select.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I am getting error 1227.. Access denied error.

Comment: This probably has more to do with your MySQL connection rather than your code. Are you sure you're able to connect to the SQL server?

Comment: yes.it's connected.iam a user not a admin.i tried grant command but no use.can u please provide a ans.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check the permissions.

Another reason for that error can be the mysql configuration option `secure-file-priv`.
Check it with `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";`

You may have to change this in your database configuration. If you are using the server for yourself alone I'd recommend to set `secure_file_priv` to `''`